# How to get rid of dustmites on the camera and accessories?

Tags: equipment-protection, cleaning, maintenance

I usually store my camera inside the carrying case which I received with my camera. Sometimes the camera lays still for several weeks without any activity.

When I took out the camera recently, I found very small [dustmites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_dust_mite) (which are barely seen) running all over the camera. I tried using silica gel, some local herbs, warming them using the sun light, etc. But they are still there.

How can I get rid of them? The problem would get worse if they get inside the lenses!

Comment: Hm... Put it in the freezer?

Comment: @Guffa I'm afraid of loosing my delicious food as well :)

Comment: How stupid would it be to freeze the camera? It must be designed to take it, right? I think I recall somebody taking a photo or two in winter. :-) Anyway, is it unduly risky to pop the buggy mess into a ziplock bag, and pop that into the freezer for a day? Ken

Comment: Nope... not risky at all. I've been shooting in 18F weather for part of this week with no problems. You could go much lower if you don't actually expect the camera to operate at those low temperatures. As you say, put it in a ziplock to minimize condensation, and let it warm up overnight before opening the bag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest taking your camera into a professional for camera cleaning. Who knows how serious the issue is - plus, I mean....termites...are you sure it isn't some other bug?

Either way, I definitely wouldn't use any harsh chemicals or substances on **my** camera - I would rather spend a little money not to ruin such an expensive device...hence the advice to seek a professional.

Comment: +1 - I too, don't recommend using any chemicals on your camera.

Answer (score 1):

It could be dust mite instead of termites. Cushion inside the case could be the inhabitat so you better change it to another case. Termites killer such as "Bora-Care" could eradicate them.

Answer (score 1):

I used to put a small amount of paradichlorobenzene crystals into a small bag, such as a desiccant bag and then leave them in the mirror chamber overnight. This damaged nothing and eradicated the mites faultlessly. I took to keeping a mothball in my camera storage cupboard thereafter. I have exactly the same issue now with a second-hand Nikon. However I am struggling to find PDB crystals for sale. It looks like an EU directive may be to blame. :( Note, I do not know how this might work on digital cameras or whether the vapour might have some effect on the CCDs, I do doubt it however.

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same problem. Switched on the camera and saw four little fuzzy bugs, apparently moving upwards, but actually moving downwards because the image is inverted by the lens. Turned off the camera and ten minutes later when I switched on again they were no longer visible. But because these creatures can reproduce as well as excrete, I decided to give it the freezer treatment. I also treated the carrying case with a synthetic pyrethrum bug spray.
Surprised that this can happen with a bridge camera (Panasonic FZ150) but I guess they get sucked in when the lens extends.
Worth bearing in mind that dust mites live in upholstery, carpets and beds, so putting your camera down on what looks like a safe surface may not always be such a good idea.